Is it possible to have the first and last swiper-button-prev/next buttons point to another html file?
Is it possible to change the functionality of the swiper-button-prev/next BUTTONS in Swiper JS?
The default functionality of the swiper-button-prev/next BUTTONS are to be disabled if you are the first image in a Swiper Thumbs Gallery or also be disabled if you are on the last slide in the gallery. Is it possible to change or replace this button with another that points you to a new html file?

Here is an example of one of the html files I generate with a script.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    <!-- Swiper JS Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

    <!-- Tigercat Stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../template/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo" onclick="window.location.href = 'Example_WI.html';" style="background-image: url('.svg');">
        </div>
        <div class="index" onclick="window.location.href = 'Index.html';" style="background-image: url('.svg');"></div>

        <!-- Swiper -->
        <div class="swiper mySlider">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide lazy">
                    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="000-000.svg"></object>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide lazy">
                    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="000-001.svg"></object>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide lazy">
                    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="000-002.svg"></object>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide lazy">
                    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="000-003.svg"></object>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide lazy">
                    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="000-004.svg"></object>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide lazy">
                    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="000-005.svg"></object>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide lazy">
                    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="000-006.svg"></object>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Navigation -->
            <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

            <!-- Pagination -->
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>

        <!-- Swiper Thumbs -->
        <div thumbslider="" class="swiper myThumbs">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img class="lazy" data-src="000-000.svg" />
                    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img class="lazy" data-src="000-001.svg" />
                    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img class="lazy" data-src="000-002.svg" />
                    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img class="lazy" data-src="000-003.svg" />
                    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img class="lazy" data-src="000-004.svg" />
                    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img class="lazy" data-src="000-005.svg" />
                    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img class="lazy" data-src="000-006.svg" />
                    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Initialize Lazy Sizes -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../template/vanilla-lazyload/dist/lazyload.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../template/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../template/js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>

Instead of placing
<!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

inside
<div class="swiper mySlider"> or <div class="swiper-wrapper">

I tried placing the Navigation buttons inside each
 <div class="swiper-slide lazy">

I felt this was duplication but was hoping that I could use the
onclick="window.location.href

on the last <div to point the button at the desired html file.


//Initialize Swiper
var swiperThumbs = new Swiper(".myThumbs", {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    spaceBetween: 6,
    breakpoints: {
        "@0.00": {
            slidesPerView: 4,
        },
        "@.75": {
            slidesPerView: 6,
        },
        "@1.00": {
            slidesPerView: 8,
        },
        "@1.50": {
            slidesPerView: 10,
        },
    },
    centeredSlides: true,
    loop: false,
    slideToClickedSlide: true,
});
var swiperSlider = new Swiper(".mySlider", {
    slidesPerView: 1,
    centeredSlides: true,
    speed: 500,
    effect: 'fade',
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    keyboard: {
        enabled: true,
    },
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination",
        type: "progressbar"
    },
});

//Initialize Vanilla Lazy-Load
var lazyLoadInstance = new LazyLoad({
    // Your custom settings go here
});

swiperThumbs.controller.control = swiperSlider;
swiperSlider.controller.control = swiperThumbs;

var thumbsHeight = document.querySelector('.myThumbs').offsetHeight; //get the height of the thumbs div
document.querySelector('.mySlider').style.height = 100 - thumbsHeight; //set the height of the slider container




Please incorporate the adjusted basic Swiper JS code below into your project and modify the buttons as you need.
Use slideChange to detect changes of slides.
To identify the first slide, use swiper.isBeginning.
While for the last slide, you can use swiper.isEnd.


const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  direction: 'horizontal',
  loop: false,

  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
});

const firstCustomButton = document.querySelector('.custom-button-first');
const lastCustomButton = document.querySelector('.custom-button-last');
const prevButton = document.querySelector('.swiper-button-prev');

swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
  const isFirstSlide = swiper.isBeginning;
  const isLastSlide = swiper.isEnd;
  if (isFirstSlide) {
    prevButton.classList.add('swiper-button-prev-hidden');
    firstCustomButton.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else if (isLastSlide) {
    lastCustomButton.classList.remove('hidden');
    prevButton.classList.add('swiper-button-prev-hidden');
  } else {
    prevButton.classList.remove('swiper-button-prev-hidden');
    firstCustomButton.classList.add('hidden');
    lastCustomButton.classList.add('hidden');
  }
});

firstCustomButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.open('https://facebook.com', '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer', 'referrerPolicy=origin');
});

lastCustomButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.open('https://facebook.com', '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer', 'referrerPolicy=origin');
});
.swiper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}

.custom-button.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.swiper-button-prev-hidden {
  display: none;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper">
  
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 1
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 2
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 3
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 4
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 5
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 6
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-prev-hidden"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  
</div>

<button class="custom-button hidden custom-button-first">
  First Slide Button
</button>
<button class="custom-button hidden custom-button-last">
  Last Slide Button
</button>




I was thinking about this more and trying the reachEnd parameter from Swiper JS. I can force the current swiper "Stage-001.html" for example to jump to a specific url "Index.html" quite easily in javascript. The problem is that instead of jumping back to the index it would be nice to jump right to "Stage-002.html" instead.
You would have to store the name of the active url when reachEnd was achieved, increment the url but one and navigate to that url instead using location.replace("")
I know very little about java.

You would still have the problem of reaching the final url and if the script increments to a value for an html file that does not exist it will fail unless you have have it fall back to returning to index.html or something.
